# date values saved to database are different with what they should be

Tags: mysql, hibernate, date, hibernate-annotations

Using hibernate and annotation, I am trying to save values to a table that has a date column (I am using Mysql). The problem is that the date values saved to database are somehow different with what the should be.
first I create a new java.sql.Date e.g.

```
Date date = new Date(2013, 10, 1);
```

but what is saved into my table is:

```
3913-02-10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are 0 based (so 1 is February), and years are 1900-based (so 2013 is 3913). That's explained in the [Date javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29). The javadoc also says that this constructor is deprecated, so you shouldn't use it anyway.

Comment: I searched a bit. seems although the constructor and most of the methods are deprecated, it is suitable when working with JDBC and date in database's tables.

Comment: @JB Nizet : another point:) well, when I get date.getYear() it is 2013... .